# problems with merge sort in java

Tags: java, mergesort

i'm brand new to stackoverflow and i need some help with writing a program to mergesort an arraylist of comparables. i have worked on this code for hours to no avail. the program needs to work correctly, because i am doing it for a computer science class, and the very next assignment requires us to test the efficiency of different sorts. here's the code:

Merge Method:

```
public static void merge(ArrayList <Comparable> a, int first, int mid, int last){
    ArrayList <Comparable> b = new ArrayList();
    for(int k = first; k <= last; k++){
        b.add(a.get(k));
    }

    System.out.println("b now contains " + b);
    int middle =b.size() /2;
    for(int i = first; i <= last; i++){
        //System.out.println("mid: " + b.size() /2);
        //System.out.println("b: " + b);
        //System.out.println("a: " + a);
        //System.out.println("i: " + i);
        if(middle == b.size()){
            a.set(i, b.remove(0));
            middle--;
        }else if(middle == 0){
            a.set(0, b.remove(0));
        }else if(b.get(0).compareTo(b.get(middle)) < 0){
            System.out.println("moving " + b.get(0) + " from b[0] to a[" + 
                i + "] because " + b.get(0) + " is less than " + b.get(middle));
            a.set(i, b.remove(0));
            middle--;
            System.out.println("b now contains " + b);
        }else{
            System.out.println("moving " + b.get(middle) + " from b[" + 
                b.size() /2 + "] to a[" + i + "] because " + b.get(0) + 
                    " is greater than " + b.get(middle));
            a.set(i, b.remove(middle));
            //middle--;
            System.out.println("b now contains " + b);
        }
    }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Merge");
    System.out.println(a);
    System.out.println();
}
```

Mergesort Method:

```
public static void mergeSort(ArrayList <Comparable> a, int first, int last){
    if(first < last){
        int mid = first + (last - first) /2;
        System.out.println("mergeSorting " + a.subList(first, last + 1));
        mergeSort(a, first, mid);
        System.out.println("mergeSorting " + a.subList(first, mid + 1));
        mergeSort(a, mid + 1, last);
        System.out.println("merging " + a.subList(first, mid + 1) + 
            " and " + a.subList(mid + 1, last + 1));
        merge(a, first, mid, last);
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("base case");
    System.out.println();
}
```

I think that there is a problem with the `merge` method, but i'm not sure.

my code seems to be sorting the list incorrectly, i.e:

```
Input:
[7,1,9,9,5,4,8,9,10,4] 

Output:
[4,8,9,4,10,10,5,9,9,7]
```

Comment: Can you give some examples of the specific errors you're getting?

Comment: The merge method doesn't appear to make any sense. Where are you getting this idea from? Can you describe, in words, what you're trying to do in the Merge function? Based on the code, I suspect you've got the wrong idea.

Comment: instead of actually merging two seperate ArrayLists, i am setting middle as a sort of seperator. the idea of my merge method is to write either the first element in b or the first element of the second half of b to the first index of a, and repeating until b is empty.

Comment: i'm not getting any errors per se, but it is not merging correctly.

Comment: You are missing one value in your output right? I just want to make sure that is not a typo :)

Comment: By the way, this would probably be easier for you to debug if you start with a smaller list. Like 3 values. then try 4 or 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mergeSort algorithm is ok. I just defined the type of ArrayList to avoid the warning

```
   public static void mergeSort(ArrayList <Comparable> a, int first, int last){
        if(first < last){
            int mid = first + (last - first) /2;
        //    System.out.println("mergeSorting " + a.subList(first, mid ));
            System.out.println("First"+first);
            System.out.println("Mid"+mid);
            System.out.println("Last"+last);
            System.out.println("MergeSortCall");
            System.out.println("firstVector " + a.subList(first, mid+1));
            System.out.println("secondVector " + a.subList(mid + 1,last+1));                
            mergeSort(a, first, mid);
            mergeSort(a, mid + 1, last);
            merge(a, first, mid, last);
            System.out.println("mergeVector " + a.subList(first,last+1));
        }

    }
```

The second part is really difficult to know exactly what is wrong so I replaced it for something much simpler using basically your notation. Note that the second part is just a "merge" algorithm. It is supposed to be really simple. Anyway, using this you can compare with your results (sorry it is difficult to understanding the logic of the second part and this is your homework, isn't it?). I'm using two vectors to improve the readability, but only one as you did is necessary.

```
public static void merge(ArrayList <Comparable> a, int first, int mid, int last){
            ArrayList <Comparable> vectorFirst = new ArrayList<Comparable>();
            ArrayList <Comparable> vectorSecond = new ArrayList<Comparable>();

            for(int k=first;k<=mid;k++){
                vectorFirst.add(a.get(k));
            }
            for(int k=mid+1;k<=last;k++){
                vectorSecond.add(a.get(k));
            }

            int i=first;
            int j=mid+1;
            int k=first-1;
            while((i<=mid)&(j<=last)){
                if(vectorFirst.get(i-first).compareTo(vectorSecond.get(j-mid-1))==-1){
                    k=k+1;
                    a.set(k,vectorFirst.get(i-first));
                    i=i+1;
                }
                else{
                     k=k+1;
                     a.set(k,vectorSecond.get(j-mid-1));
                     j=j+1;
                }
            }
            if(i==mid+1){
                while(j<=last){
                    k=k+1;
                    a.set(k,vectorSecond.get(j-mid-1));
                    j=j+1;
                }
            }
            else{
                while(i<=mid){
                    k=k+1;
                    a.set(k,vectorFirst.get(i-first));
                    i=i+1;
                }
            }


        }
```

Comment: @user3325257 I had forgoten using "comparable". Now I think it is ok.

Comment: There is a version of mergesort here http://www.censore.blogspot.in/2014/08/java-merge-sort-source-code.html